# Filename length limit in mixture

Tags: html, filenames, mixture-model, static-site

```
c_program_to_find_fibonacci_series_using_loop.html
```

tried this filename and mixture giving page not found error when I removed some letters from it then it shows the page.
I think this is not limit for filenames.
atleast 255 letters can be used. Is this a problem with Mixture? but my server also not showing the file

Comment: Not trying to sound bad, but... are you sure you didn't misspell the file name? and then by removing some letters you removed the typo and the file worked? I know Fibonacci can be tricky to write correctly sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

There is a physical limit to filename lengths according to OS. In general 255 characters max. 
Other conventions: http://demosthenes.info/blog/30/HTML-naming-conventions-and-file-management